# How to add DOM element (with controller) into AngularJS scope dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to build an application (using AngularJS) which allows me to drag a complex HTML element which MAY include angular controller calls from a palette into a div.

The drag/drop portion is working, however I am not able to get the element clone into the scope.

I have a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/gdharley/h4AcC/

Basically, when the element is dropped, I am emitting an event that is picked up by the mainController.

```
$scope.$on('my-created', function (ev, val) {
    $scope.items.splice(val.to, 0, {
        name: val.name
    });
    var myInjector = angular.injector(["ng", "plunker"]);
    var $compile = myInjector.get("$compile"); // retrieve the compile service
    var fnLink = $compile(val); // returns a Link function used to bind element to the scope
    fnLink($scope);
})
```

I am then retrieving the compile service from the injector and compiling he element into the scope.

While no errors are thrown, the clone of the element is not functional (i.e. adding contacts does not appear to call the add() function in the controller.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't put things in the DOM with your controller. You do it in a directive. Even then, you don't need any of that. Just have your "add()" function add things to your model and use ng-repeat to output more.

Everything you're doing should be based around changing a model. It's hard for me to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve, but the result of a drag-drop should modify your model and angular can react based on watches or emits, but you shouldn't be compiling anything manually most of the time.

If you do need to compile do it inside your directive, not your controller. Just inject the `$compile` service and call it that way.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, while the simple sample I provided looks as though you ciould use a model with ng-repeat, the actual use case is not well suited to that pattern as we will not be placing controls (the example here being the email list) into a simple list. There are layout considerations. Still, I do appreciate your tip on injecting the $compile service as I was struggling with how injection annotations work, it's very different to any other language I've worked with before.

Comment: If not ng-repeat, another custom directive. You never want to modify your DOM from a controller. It's a huge temptation for people who are familiar with jQuery but it will handicap you in the long run. I don't fully understand the context of what you're trying to create but I can tell you that there is a way to make it model-centric and have custom directives do the visuals. You will be happier in the long run if you can figure this out.